# jQuery dataTable reload from new ajax source

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery Datatable plugin. The init code is like below

```
$('#Table').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": url
    ...
    ...
});
```

which gets fired on click of a button.Now on click of that button again I want to get the dataTable with a different url.
I have tried using without success.Please suggest.

```
if (typeof obj == 'undefined') {

    obj = $('#Table').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": url
    ...
    ...
    })
}else
{
    obj.fnClearTable(0);
    obj.fnDraw(false);

}
```

Answer (score 10):

I think what you need is [fnReloadAjax()](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnReloadAjax) . You should use it like this:

```
var oTable = $('#Table').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": url
    ...
    ...
}); 

var newUrl = "new.php";

oTable.fnReloadAjax(newUrl);
```

Comment: same problem your method not working for me,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246666/datatables-fnreloadajax-is-not-working-properly.
I read the docs, i know it should work but i dont understand why it is not working for me..

Answer (score 4):

Try with this link: http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url()

> var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
>       ajax: "data.json" } );
>   table.ajax.url( 'newData.json' ).load();

or as I did if table is not a dataTable object:

> $('#tableId').DataTable().ajax.url("newUrl").load();

Answer (score 2):

This work for me:

```
var table = $('#Table').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": url
    ...
    ...
}); 

url = 'newajax.php';

console.log('change input listened');
table.ajax.url(url);
table.draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for version 1.10:

```
   oTable.ajax.url("new_source_file.php");
   oTable.draw();
```