# datatables | fnreloadajax() is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Im trying to reload the datatables from new ajax source.

i mean on page load it loads from 1 source, but after some action on page, it needs to be loaded from another source.

i am trying it through `fnreloadajax()` but it is not working, i mean all fnreload ajax do, it reloads the table but not from the new source??

i did read the docs for `fnreloadajax()`
http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax

but when i tried like this.

```
        var GroupID = e.val;
        url = "admin/usersManagePermissions/listFormsInGroups_DT/"+GroupID;
        oTable.fnReloadAjax(url);
```

i got no error, but also datatables dont reload the table from new source. it only loads the table from previous/original source which was defined to it.

what is wrong here?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart
Sorry, i didn't noticed it. Next time i will.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem today, here is my solution:

This is the datatable objet, be careful, DataTable() != dataTable() see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207147/datatable-vs-datatable-why-is-there-a-difference-and-how-do-i-make-them-w).

```
var tableRestr = $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
                    ajax: someUrl});
```

Then, always when I need to reload from another url, just use this two lines:

```
tableRestr.ajax.url(newUrl);
tableRestr.ajax.reload();
```